# MySql: Select value of current and next row

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am trying to learn of a better way in achieving the desired result of a select query - details below, thank you in advance.

MySQL version: 5.7

Table:
id int(11)
product_number int(8)
service_group int (4)
datetime datetime
value int (6)

Indexes on all but value column.

### MySql table has the following data:

```
id,product_number, service_group,datetime,value
1,1234,1,2022-02-10 00:00:00,0
2,1234,1,2022-02-10 00:01:30,25
3,1234,1,2022-02-10 00:02:30,11
4,1234,2,2022-02-10 01:00:30,0
5,1234,2,2022-02-10 01:01:30,65
6,1234,2,2022-02-10 01:02:30,55
```

In essence, the value for each product within the service group is wrongly recorded, and the correct value for the "current" row is actually recorded against the next row for the product within the same service group - correct output should look like this:

```
id,product_number, service_group,datetime,value
1,1234,1,2022-02-10 00:00:00,25
2,1234,1,2022-02-10 00:01:30,11
3,1234,1,2022-02-10 00:02:30,0
4,1234,2,2022-02-10 01:00:30,65
5,1234,2,2022-02-10 01:01:30,55
6,1234,2,2022-02-10 01:02:30,0
```

The below query is what seems to be hugely inefficient way of returning the correct results - what would be a better way to go about this in MySql? Thank you.

````
Select 
    a.id,
    a.product_number, 
    a.service_group,
    a.datetime,
    (
    Select b.value FROM products b
    Where b.product_number=a.product_number AND b.service_group=a.service_group
    AND b.datetime>a.datetime
    Order by b.datetime ASC
    Limit 1
    )
FROM products a```
````

Comment: Which version of MySQL? What is your table definition, including ALL indexes? Have you run EXPLAIN? (Add the explain plan to your question.). Are your rows always one minute apart? If the gap is more than one minute, should the same rules apply any way?

Comment: Hi. MySql version 5.7.

Comment: There is a difference between two indexes on one column each and one index on two columns. Please include the ***actual*** definitions of ***all*** indexes.

Comment: The MySql 5.7 platform dates back to around 2004. Yes, I know the specific version is more recent, but the platform is effectively unchanged. It doesn't really even qualify as a modern database product. You really ought to get up to 8.0. That has features like LAG and LEAD that directly address this question.

Comment: Are the ids consecutive within a product - service group pair or can you have gaps in them?

Comment: Hi. I am specifically interested in a technique of achieving the output in a better way, the query I posted works fine, it is just slow when a lot of data builds up. @Shadow - typically the readings are coming for multiple products at different times, the id auto-increase on first-come basis.

Comment: That way to do it faster is using **windowing functions**, but that requires a modern platform like MySql 8.

Comment: @ Joel Coehoorn - sure, but this is not practically possible at the current moment, so I have to make the best of what I have. Have you got an advice that could help the current situation?

Comment: A compound index on `(product_number, service_group, datetime, value)` *(all four columns, in one index, in that order)* would be optimal for your query. But as you refused to include full table definitions or explain plan, we can't tell what you already have. You could use unreliable hacks using variables, but they have numerous side-effects that trip people up *(and there are dozens of SO answers enumerating how to do that already)*.  My best advise is to actually provide the information requested, and not cherry pick what you're going to include.

Comment: MatBailie, thank you for the compound index advise. Consider this: what if I was not "cherry picking" as you put it, but am trying to present a simple example of a problem with EXAMPLE data?? The whole point of me coming to ask the experts around here is to learn, not for you to solve a specific case for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no skipped id (the number is in sequence) then you could probably use simple select like below

1.

```
Select 
    a.id,
    a.product_number, 
    a.service_group,
    a.datetime,
    (Select b.value FROM products b Where b.id = a.id+1)
FROM products a
```

2. 

```
Select 
    a.id,
    a.product_number, 
    a.service_group,
    a.datetime,
    b.value
FROM products a
INNER JOIN products b ON b.id = a.id+1
```

Note that both SQL 1 and 2 is assuming your ID is primary key as I see that's an incrementing value

Either way you need to run an explain query so you could analyze which one is the most efficient one

And more importantly I suggest to update it if it's "wrongly recorded", you should put the your service on maintenance mode and do update+fix on the data using query

Edit:
based on your comment "Hi, Gunawan. Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately IDs will not be in sequences to support the proposed approach."

You could alter the subquery on (1) a bit to

```
Select b.value 
FROM products b 
Where b.id > a.id order by id asc limit 1
```

so it became

```
Select 
    a.id,
    a.product_number, 
    a.service_group,
    a.datetime,
    (Select b.value FROM products b Where b.id > a.id order by b.id asc limit 1)
FROM products a
```

Comment: Hi, Gunawan. Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately IDs will not be in sequences to support the proposed approach.

Comment: i update the code based on your comment, I update the subquery

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need in THIS case is the Windows LEAD() function and can be found [Here for example and clarification](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-lead-and-lag-function/)

In summary, LEAD() looks at the NEXT possible record for the given column in question, LAG() looks at the prior.

So in this example, I am asking for the LEAD() of the record (the next one in line) and getting the `VALUE` column of that record.  The 1 represents how many records to skip ahead, in this case 1.  The last parameter 0 is what should be returned if no such record exists.

The second half of the clause with the ORDER BY clause identifies how you want the records returned, in this case the `datetime` sequence.

I included both the value and the NEXTVALUE so you could see the results, but can remove the extra column once you see and understand how it works.

But since you have each service group to its own, and dont want to carry-over the value from another, you need the PARTITION clause as well.  So I added that as an additional column... both so you can see how the results work with OR without it and the impact of the query you need.

```
select 
        t.id,
        t.product_number,
        t.service_group,
        t.datetime,
        t.value,
--        lead (t.value, 1, 0) 
--            over (order by t.datetime) as NextValue,
        -- without the ,1, 0 in the lead call as sample above
        -- you can see the NULLs are not getting the value
        -- from the next row when the service group changes.
        lead (t.value) 
            over ( PARTITION BY 
                        t.service_group 
                    order by 
                        t.datetime) as NextValuePerServiceGroup
    from 
        Tmp1 t
    order by
        t.service_group,
        t.datetime
```